# Must ListView.Builder widget be placed on a separate page or not

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart

I am having problem displaying results using ListView.Builder widget. When i placed it on the main.dart page no matter what i do, the page constantly coming up with render errors. Immediately i put it in a separate page, it displayed correctly without error. The page(main.dart) display perfectly without any error without the listView.builder.
My question is it possible or otherwise to display ListView.Builder alongside other widgets on the same page or must it be displayed on a separate page?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      // child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child:Container(
                        child: Column(
                          //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(

                                  child:Expanded(
                                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/1frenchToast.webp"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Select Cuisine",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  child: DropdownButton(
                                    //isDense: true,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.black,),
                                    value: dropDownSelectedItemState,
                                    items: items,
                                    onChanged: (String selectValue){
                                      ClassHub().mySharedPreference("cuisineChoice", "set", selectValue);

                                      ClassHub().getFoodCategory(selectValue).then((onValue){
                                        if(onValue !=null){
                                          setState(() {
                                            foodCategory = onValue;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      });
                                      setState(() {
                                        dropDownSelectedItemState = selectValue;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  onLongPress: (){

                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

 // This is the portion causing issues
                            Column(
                              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: <Widget>[

                                //myListView(),

                               Container(
                                 child: ListView.builder(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  itemCount: foodCategory.length
                                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                    return ListTile(
                                      title: Text(foodCategory[index].foodType),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                            ),

                              ]
                            ),
                            Container(
                              //height: 20,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20,),
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                                      minRadius: 10,
                                      maxRadius: 30,
                                          //child:Image.asset("assets/images/Capture.JPG",height: 60,width: 60,),
                                      //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/Capture.JPG'),
                                    ),
                                    title: Text("Western Food Recipes"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,
                                  child:ListTile(
                                    leading: Image.asset("assets/images/Capture.JPG"),
                                     // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                   // ),
                                    title: Text("African Food Recipes"),
                                  ),
                                ),

                              ],
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,
                                  child:ListTile(
                                    leading: Image.asset("assets/images/Capture.JPG"),
                                    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    // ),
                                    title: Text("African Food Recipes"),
                                  ),
                                ),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      // ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

I want to be able to display ListView.Builder widget on the same page with other widgets without any render error. Is this possible or not?

Comment: its a widget, its not necessary to move it another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `shrinkWrap = true` inside ListView.builder.

Else the children will wont know how much space to take in the scrollable widget.

Comment: BouncingScrollPhysics() doesn't work with ``shrinkWrap = true``. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @Vidor Vistrom, thanks for your useful reply. shrinkwrap: true, made the ListView.builder display correctly, but please one more thing. The listview content is not scrolling, but the whole page is. There is SingleChildScrollView for the page, and another for the ListView.builder. How can i make the Listview.builder content to also be scrolling. And is it possible to put multiple singlechildscrollview on a page. Thanks once again.

Comment: @defemz try adding physics to list view as AlwaysScrollablePhysics()

Comment: @VidorVistrom thanks once again. adding physics to ListView as AlwaysScrollablePhysics() does not have any effect whatsoever.

Comment: @defemz I see.. thats because your all the elements are inflated in the space and are taking their appropriate height. There is no sense of scrolling them separately then. What you can do is, wrap you listview inside a container and give that container a fixed height. And rest is same. You will have a listview larger than the height of the container hence there will be scroll involved

Comment: @VidorVistrom Wow, thanks mate, your last reply has completely solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to pass the `builder_context` and use this is `ListView.Builder` function it might help you